# Empty value for string in model function

Tags: django, django-models

First project newbie here - In this model I am trying to create a field that combines first and last names of two people depending if the last names are the same or not. If the last name is the same, I want it to display as "first_name1 & first_name2 last_name1".  It works except that when last_name1 is empty, which will be the case a lot of the time, it displays something like "John & Jane None". I had to specify last_name1 as a string or else I got an error:  must be str, not NoneType.  How do I do this properly? Also what do I call this type of function in a model...is it a manager? I wasn't sure how to title this post.

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    first_name1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='First Name', null=True)
    last_name1 = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Last Name', null=True, blank=True)
    first_name2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='First Name (Second Person)', null=True, blank=True)
    last_name2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Last Name (Second Person)', null=True, blank=True)

    def get_full_name(self):
        combined_name = ''

        if self.last_name1 == self.last_name2:
            combined_name = self.first_name1 + ' & ' + self.first_name2 + ' ' + str(self.last_name1)

        return '%s' % (combined_name)

    full_name = property(get_full_name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason on why you're getting an error that last_name1 must be a String, not a NoneType is due to the fact you've set null to True in your field declaration for the said field.

So what's wrong with doing that? When you are defining null=True for fields like CharField or TextField you'll end up having ***None***. The Django convention is to use ***EMPTY STRING***.

Here's a [link](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/07/25/django-tip-8-blank-or-null.html) that talks about how you would use **blank** or **null** on field declarations.

Comment: That's it... I removed the null=True on those fields and had to delete all the database entries and re-add them. Now it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but you can still end up with `'Jane & John '`. Note the trailing whitespace too.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if those values are "Truth-y" before doing the comparison check. However, you'll need to decide how to handle the other cases.

```
@property
def get_full_name(self):
    combined_name = ''
    if self.last_name1 and self.last_name2:
        if self.last_name1 == self.last_name2:
            combined_name = self.first_name1 + ' & ' + self.first_name2 + ' ' + str(self.last_name1)
    elif self.last_name1:  # Only last_name1 is set
        pass
    elif self.last_name2:  # Only last_name2 is set
        pass
    else: # Both last_name1 and last_name2 are None or ''
        pass

    return combined_name
```

Comment: why not simply `return combined_name`?

Comment: That's a reasonable question, but likely requires context from the actual code. If it was simply a case/switch statement like it appears, I would personally return. I know other developers that wouldn't because they like to try to limit the returns of a function to a single spot. It's a matter of preference and I don't think either case provides a significant improvement so I left it the same.

Comment: I meant `return combined_name` instead of `return f'{combined_name}'` -- the second version is just copying a string into another string before returning it...?

Comment: D'oh. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The way you've defined the names, any and all of them can be `None`, if you change them to the empty string you'll have similar problems. To illustrate, lets start by writing a unit test (substitute the empty string for None if you want):

```
def test_contact_full_name():
    # correct.
    assert Contact('Jane', None, 'John', None).full_name == "Jane & John"
    assert Contact('Bart', 'Simpson', 'Lisa', 'Simpson').full_name  == "Bart & Lisa Simpson"
    assert Contact('Bart', 'Simpson', 'Frodo', 'Baggins').full_name == "Bart Simpson & Frodo Baggins"
    assert Contact('Bart', None, None, None).full_name == "Bart"
    assert Contact('Bart', 'Simpson', None, None).full_name == "Bart Simpson"
    assert Contact(None, 'Simpson', None, None).full_name == "Simpson"

    assert Contact(None, None, None, None).full_name == ""

    # correct?
    assert Contact('Bart', 'Simpson', 'Lisa', None).full_name == "Bart Simpson & Lisa"

    # correct??
    assert Contact('Bart', None, 'Lisa', 'Simpson').full_name == "Bart & Lisa Simpson"
```

Then it's just a question of dividing the problem into smaller pieces, I've put everything into a regular class just to make it easier to test. First some helper methods:

```
class Contact(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        self.first_name1 = a
        self.last_name1 = b
        self.first_name2 = c
        self.last_name2 = d

    def combined_last_name(self, a, b):
        "Return ``a`` if ``a`` and ``b`` are equal, otherwise returns None."
        return a if a and b and a == b else None

    def normalize_name(self, n):
        "Returns the name or the empty string if ``n`` is None."
        return n if n else ""

    def get_name(self, f, l):
        """Returns a string containing firstname lastname and omits any of them
           if they're None.
        """         
        if f and l:
            return "%s %s" % (f, l)
        if f:
            return f
        elif l:
            return l
        return ""

    def has_second_name(self):
        "Returns true if there is a second name."
        return self.first_name2 or self.last_name2
```

then we can define the `full_name` property:

```
    @property
    def full_name(self):
        """Returns a string that combines first and last names of two people
           depending if the last names are the same or not. If the last name
           is the same, it displays as::

               first_name1 & first_name2 last_name1

        """
        cln = self.combined_last_name(self.last_name1, self.last_name2)
        if cln:  # have a common last name..
            return "%s & %s %s" % (
                self.first_name1,
                self.first_name2,
                cln
            )
        elif self.has_second_name():
            return "%s & %s" % (
                self.get_name(self.first_name1, self.last_name1),
                self.get_name(self.first_name2, self.last_name2)
            )
        else:
            return self.get_name(self.first_name1, self.last_name1)
```

if we put everything in a file named `fullname.py` we can use the `pytest` tool (`pip install pytest`) to run the tests:

```
c:\srv\tmp> pytest --verbose fullname.py
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 2.7.16, pytest-3.3.1, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0 -- c:\srv\venv\finautfaktura\scripts\python.exe
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: c:\srv\tmp, inifile:
plugins: xdist-1.20.1, forked-0.2, django-3.1.2, cov-2.5.1
collected 1 item

fullname.py::test_contact_full_name PASSED                               [100%]

========================== 1 passed in 0.20 seconds ===========================
```

All is well... or is it?

Let's write another test:

```
def test_only_second_name():
    assert Contact(None, None, None, "Simpson").full_name == "Simpson"
    assert Contact(None, None, "Lisa", "Simpson").full_name == "Lisa Simpson"
    assert Contact(None, None, "Lisa", None).full_name == "Lisa"
```

running pytest again reveals the (first) error:

```
c:\srv\tmp> pytest --verbose fullname.py
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 2.7.16, pytest-3.3.1, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0 -- c:\srv\venv\finautfaktura\scripts\python.exe
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: c:\srv\tmp, inifile:
plugins: xdist-1.20.1, forked-0.2, django-3.1.2, cov-2.5.1
collected 2 items

fullname.py::test_contact_full_name PASSED                               [ 50%]
fullname.py::test_only_second_name FAILED                                [100%]

================================== FAILURES ===================================
____________________________ test_only_second_name ____________________________

    def test_only_second_name():
>       assert Contact(None, None, None, "Simpson").full_name == "Simpson"
E       AssertionError: assert ' & Simpson' == 'Simpson'
E         -  & Simpson
E         ? ---
E         + Simpson

fullname.py:83: AssertionError
===================== 1 failed, 1 passed in 0.37 seconds ======================
```

i.e. the property returned `" & Simpson"` instead of the expected `"Simpson"` for the first assert.

To fix this we can make the `full_name` property handle this added complexity as well, or.., we can solve the problem somewhere else, e.g. in the `__init__`:

```
class Contact(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        self.first_name1 = a
        self.last_name1 = b
        self.first_name2 = c
        self.last_name2 = d
        if not a and not b:
            # if no name1, then put name2 into name1 and set name2 to None
            self.first_name1 = self.first_name2
            self.last_name1 = self.last_name2
            self.first_name2 = self.last_name2 = None
```

running pytest again shows that this fixed the second test.

You can of course not provide your own `__init__` in a Django model to solve this problem, but you can do something similar in if you override the `save(..)` method:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.first_name1 and not self.last_name1:
        self.first_name1 = self.first_name2
        self.last_name1 = self.last_name2
        self.first_name2 = self.last_name2 = None
    super(Contact, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```